# *ionic android* Only ionic --livereload option is working. ionic emulate android is not working

Tags: android, android-emulator, ionic-framework, livereload

I am using ionic for developing my application.
When I run using android emulator, I usually type "ionic emulate android"

However, when I execute like that all functions are working well except one thing.

However, when I execute using "ionic emulate --livereload android", it works fine all.

I don't know how can I fix this problem. When I make apk file and install into real device, it is not working well as I mentioned above.

Is there any way to build android application like using --livereload ?

Acutally, I added "asynchrous call" and "$ionicLoading" so that it gets more time to load page..

But, it didn't work when I use "ionic emulate android".

Help me please.

Thanks,

Comment: have you tried "ionic serve" command? it will open application on browser!

Comment: can you specify what is not working? does the app not start / is it the white screen of death?